# SVG Error: <path> attribute d: Unexpected end of attribute

Tags: html, svg

I'm getting a browser console error from an SVG path. I'm not sure how to fix this, or which part of the path is incorrectly configured (I didn't make the path).

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Unexpected end of attribute. Expected number, "….907L9.5 0l2.792".
```

```
<path d="M9.5 14.25l-5.584 2.936 1.066-6.218L.465 6.564l6.243-.907L9.5 0l2.792" />
```

Is anyone able to tell help me out here? I know there have been a couple of similar questions - please don't mark as duplicate, each path is unique. Thanks.

Comment: l has to have 2 numbers following it, your final l only has one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the path has been **manually** cropped/clipped by stripping some parts of the svg markup.

#### The reason for this error:

There is an incomplete ***l*** – relative lineto command – missing a y coordinate.
You should also close your path by a ***z*** command.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
   <path d="M9.5 14.25l-5.584 2.936 1.066-6.218L.465 6.564l6.243-0.907L9.5 0z" />
</svg>
```

#### Troubleshooting recommendations

**'Dissect'** your path's `d` attribute to get a better understanding of its structure.

A great tool for this task is [Yann Armelin's svg-path-editor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor)
It also helps converting commands from relative to absolute.

**Manually: So you're already familiar with [all kinds of path commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d)**
Rewrite/breakdown your `d` values to a more verbose readable version like this:

| short | long |
| --- | --- |
| M9.5 14.25 | **M** 9.5 14.25 |
| l-5.584 2.936 | **l** -5.584 2.936 (relative command) |
| 1.066-6.218 | **l** 1.066 -6.218 (still a `l` command – shorthand) |
| L.465 6.564l6 | **L** 0.465 6.564l6 (absolute `L` command, leading zeroes are ommitted) |
| l6.243 -.907 | **l** 6.243 -0.907 (relative `l` command, leading zeroes are ommitted) |
| L9.5 0 | **L** 9.5 0 (absolute `L` command) |
| l2.792 | **l** 2.792 (relative `l` command – **hey! where's the y coordinate?**) |

Answer (score 1):

Try pasting the complete svg markup into this tool : https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/    Sometimes it will fix malformed paths.

I tried doing it and I see half of a star. Not sure if that's correct. I had to guess at its dimensions though since you didn't include the rest of the svg, so its not a very good test.